# How to check if Java 7 version is installed via Cocoa?

Tags: java, xcode, cocoa

I have an Cocoa Xcode application that I am writing and I need to check what Java versions are installed on the user's machine.  I know I can check `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/` and see what folders exist; however, this does not work for Java 7.

When I installed Java 7 on my Mac OS X 10.7.5, it was installed to `/Library/Internet Plugins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin`.  But this doesn't let me know the version of Java that is installed.  If a newer version of Java is installed, I'm assuming it will install to the same place.

If I need to test if Java 7+ JRE is installed on the user's machine, should I just check if the file `/Library/Internet Plugins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin` exists?  Is there a better way to check?

Comment: You can always parse `java -version` but I feel this is not what you are looking for... Another solution would be to grab, or create, a very small jar create with a JDK 7 and try and run it with the `java` command: if it fails, the bytecode is too recent for your JVM.

Comment: @fge When I installed Java 7, my `java -version` didn't update to say 1.7 (it still says 1.6).

Comment: Then it certainly means this is java 6. Are you sure you installed the JRE and not only the plugin? Note: I don't use Mac OS X nor the Java plugin...

Comment: @fge Yeah, I have Java 7 installed on my machine, that isn't the question.  If you run `"/Library/Internet Plugins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java" -version` you get `...(build 1.7.0_21-b12)...`.  The installer doesn't change the command line shortcut of `java` to the new version.

Comment: @Ivan - What you're saying is that, even though Java 7 is installed, everything that uses Java is getting Java 6, because that's where the system PATH points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you may have installed Java 7, you should have installed the Apple's Java Mac OS X 2012-006 update before. Having done that (and then installed java 7 again), java -version should tell you java version "1.7.x..."

[Determining the Default Version of the JDK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html#version)

Comment: I doubt users will know to do this; from testing, most don't know how to install Java.  This doesn't actually solve the problem of determining if Java 7 is installed via Cocoa.

Comment: I think you need java for something else than checking its version. If you cannot be sure that the java -version is telling you the latest version installed, you will have to check the JavaAppletPlugin.plugin bundle. After that you will need to use that full path (..../java) to run any jar you need. In a project I am working on, it was decided to include a java installation folder and to use that one instead of the user's (I think a jar here required webviews or something like that, only working in java7), but just copying it (instead of "installing" it).

Comment: Are you allowed to redistribute the Java jar?  If so, I think that might be the one of the best things to do.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the answer: http://java.com/en/download/faq/distribution.xml#eula

Comment: According to this FAQ (http://java.com/en/download/faq/distribution.xml) you can distribute Java within your releases. (Do not forget to check the specific version license).